# Extra 301 redirect with nginx and uwsgi

Tags: nginx, rewrite, uwsgi

I've the following nginx conf:

```
server {
    server_name tawp.in;

    location / {
            rewrite ^/r/([^/]*)$ /s/ta/$1;
            rewrite ^/e/(.*)$ /en/ta/$1;

            uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;

            uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR  /home/yuvipanda/sites/wikishortipy;
            uwsgi_param UWSGI_CALLABLE app;
            uwsgi_param UWSGI_MODULE app;
            uwsgi_param UWSGI_FILE /home/yuvipanda/sites/wikishortipy/app.py;
            uwsgi_param UWSGI_SETENV WIKISHORTIPY_SETTINGS=/home/yuvipanda/sites/wikishortipy/settings.py;
            include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I'd expect the two rewrite rules to just rewrite **internally**, but they're causing external 301 redirects to be sent. What am I doing wrong?

You can check the site at tawp.in/r/3 to see the extra redirect.

**Edit**: Adding the `last` flag to the rewrites doesn't help (as it shouldn't)

Comment: What `Location` header is the 301 sending?  Any chance that the python code is throwing it and not nginx?

Comment: Python *is* sending the 301. But initial redirect from r/x to r/ta/x should be internal, no?

Answer (score 1):

directive "break" will stop rewrite module working. If you using break inside location, your request will be proceed in it, so:

```
rewrite ^/r/([^/]*)$ /s/ta/$1 break;
rewrite ^/e/(.*)$ /en/ta/$1 break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the `last` keyword to your rewrite rules, like this:

```
rewrite ^/r/([^/]*)$ /s/ta/$1 last;
rewrite ^/e/(.*)$ /en/ta/$1 last;
```

Comment: No luck - no effect in this case, just as the docs predicted